# algebra problem - homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, continuous-homomorphisms

[image]

[image]

help me to solve this problem please this is my soultion but i am not sure if it is correct

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider writing MathJax instead of pasting images. That would be very kind, since handwritten notes could be a problem for people. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of a is perfect. The proof of b is not wrong but is too long and unnecessarily repeats the inductive argument. When you get to $\frac{1}{f(a^k)}$ just use part a of the problem to simplify (you can do this because $k$ is positive) and you are done!